# Example of Edge-transitive

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for graph $G$ such that $G$ is edge-transitive but $G^c$ is not edge-transitive.

My conjecture:If $G$ is edge-transitive then $G^c$ is edge-transitive

Please advise me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy counterexample - the graph which is edge-transitive and its complement is not: simply take one edge in $K_4$ as you graph. (The complement is $K_4$ with one edge omitted.)

Graph:

[image: line in K4]

Complement:

[image: Complement of line in K4]

Complement can be redrawn like this:

[image: Different plot of the same graph]

Note that the edge joining the vertices of degree 3 cannot be mapped to any other edge.